# Standard zoom lens recommendation

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, used-equipment, canon-650d

Am planning to buy a zoom lens for my upcomming trip.I have Canon650D and Tokina 11-16 lens with me .My clicks mainly involve landscape, architecture.
I want to know out of the below lens which I one is the best in terms of performance and image quality.**Please suggest 3 lens**.

- Tamron AF 18-200mm F/3.5-6.3 XR Di-II LD Aspherical
- Tamron 18-270mm F/3.5 6.3 Di II VC PZD
- Sigma 18-200mm F/3.5-6.3 II DC OS
- Tamron SP AF 17-50mm F/2.8 XR Di II LD
- Canon EF-S18-200mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
- Canon EF 28-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM
- Canon EF-S 18-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS

Comment: I would suggest some research on a lens review site is the optimal approach. Here, people are either going to have to do that research for you or offer their opinion, which is why the close votes.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed aperture is a very good feature that only one of those has. It just makes it easier to meter, control dof, and use fill flash. So go for the tamron. It is even pretty sharp. and super zooms are never a good idea, as they really make you feel disappointed at your DSLR.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a guarantee, but a general rule of thumb is that the longer the range of focal lengths, the lower quality the lens.  The majority of those lenses have extreme focal ranges.  Beyond that, shopping questions are generally considered off topic and this is very much a shopping question.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that your main subjects are landscape and architecture, for these 2 you will mostly need the wide lens, specially for architecture, and the Tokina 11-16mm will be great for that use.

The lenses you listed are all super zoom lenses and I don't think you'll ever have to use 100mm or more in landscape and architecture photography. The super zoom lenses are mainly used as "one all around lens" that you can take to a trip but it you're not going to shoot birds or something that required the super zoom I don't see the point of buying such lens.

Due to the poor quality of super lenses, you will shoot your main subjects with the Tokina, so the wide range is covered. I think you may want to consider some other lenses with smaller range - a thumb rule will be a max X3 zoom, usually lenses with Maximum focal Length/Minimum focal length < 3 are better in terms of optical quality.

The Tamron SP AF 17-50mm F/2.8 XR Di II LD will complete most of the range you will use but if I can recommend some other lenses I would say you should check out the Canon EF-S 17-85mm f/4-5.6 IS USM. The Canon 17-85 is not the best quality you'll get but it not too expensive and for my opinion completes your range better.

If you're looking for higher quality you can check out the Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS USM.
obviously it's much more expensive but it's an "L" lens and you will enjoy it.

**Note:** Super zoom lens have a smaller aperture at the far end and usually to get sharper image you will want to close the aperture even more. That results in a very slow lens. Moreover the quality of these lenses at the far end is poor.